# Angular animations as a separate file not in-lined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-animations

I've been fiddling with [Angular animations](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/animations.html) and was wondering if there's a best/recommended way to avoid inline styling ... for instance,

```
@Component({
selector: 'page-that-needs-anime',
templateUrl: './anime.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./anime.component.scss'],
animations: [
trigger('animeTrigger', [
state('in', style({transform: 'translateY(0)'})),
transition('void => *', [
  animate(700, keyframes([
    style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-100%)', offset: 0}),
    style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(25px)',  offset: 0.3}),
    style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)',     offset: 1.0})
  ]))
]) //you get the idea ... *Import statement is taken out for brevity
```

Anyway the "animations" could use a reference like styleUrls & templateUrl above? I've seen someone referred it as a const but was wondering if there was an 'Angular official' way.

Comment: have you tried including the `transition` in your `.scss`?

Answer (score 38):

You can keep your animations in separate files.

```
// animations.ts
import { trigger, state, style, transition, animate } from '@angular/animations';

export const Animations = {
    animeTrigger: trigger('animeTrigger', [
        state('in', style({transform: 'translateY(0)'})),
        transition('void => *', [
        animate(700, keyframes([
            style({opacity: 0, transform: 'translateY(-100%)', offset: 0}),
            style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(25px)',  offset: 0.3}),
            style({opacity: 1, transform: 'translateY(0)',     offset: 1.0}) 
        ]))
    ])

}
```

Component

```
import { Animations } from './animations'

@Component({
    selector: 'page-that-needs-anime',
    templateUrl: './anime.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./anime.component.scss'],
    animations: [
        Animations.animeTrigger
    ]
})
```

Comment: Is it possible to import in in the app module? I tried to do it and failed. So I don't have to import it in each file I want to do the transitions.

Answer (score 3):

Taken from the documentation:

> **Creating reusable animations**
>
> To create a reusable animation, use the animation() method to define an 
>   animation in a separate .ts file
>   and declare this animation definition as a const export variable. You
>   can then import and reuse this animation in any of your app components
>   using the useAnimation() API.
>
> ```
> *src/app/animations.ts*
>
> import {
>   animation, trigger, animateChild, group,
>   transition, animate, style, query
> } from '@angular/animations';
>
> export const transAnimation = animation([
>   style({
>     height: '{{ height }}',
>     opacity: '{{ opacity }}',
>     backgroundColor: '{{ backgroundColor }}'
>   }),
>   animate('{{ time }}')
> ]);
> ```
>
> In the above code snippet, transAnimation is made reusable by
>   declaring it as an export variable.
>
> > Note: The height, opacity, backgroundColor, and time inputs are
> >     replaced during runtime.
>
> You can import the reusable transAnimation variable in your component
>   class and reuse it using the useAnimation() method as shown below.
>
> ```
> *src/app/open-close.component.ts*
>
> import { Component } from '@angular/core';
> import { useAnimation, transition, trigger, style, animate } from '@angular/animations';
> import { transAnimation } from './animations';
>
> @Component({
>     trigger('openClose', [
>       transition('open => closed', [
>         useAnimation(transAnimation, {
>           params: {
>             height: 0,
>             opacity: 1,
>             backgroundColor: 'red',
>             time: '1s'
>           }
>         })
>       ])
>     ])
>   ],
> })
> ```

Quoted from: https://angular.io/guide/reusable-animations